# Display the taxonomy term name in the page.tpl from a node

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

I want to show the term name in the header for every node. Whats the best way, espacially if the node has 2 fields with taxonomy terms and the page is in different languages.

This display nothing, but gives me also no errors:

```
<?php if ( !empty($node) && $node->type == 'content-type') {
  print render(field_custom('node', $node, 'field_custom', array('label'=>'hidden', )));
} 
?>
```

**EDIT**

preprocess_node:

```
global $language;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
$variables['term1'] = $variables['term1'] ->language($language->language)->field_term_ref->value()->name;
```

page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $term1 ?>
```

I don`t get any term name.

Comment: What modules are you using for different languages and what field of taxonomy term do you want to display?

Comment: You have a syntax error. You need a closing single quote after 'field_custom'.

Comment: i use i18n, ctools, views and have 6 content types. one content type with 2 term fields and two with one term field. in total i use 4 taxonomies. That was the only way to merge the complexity of the site. little bit hard to explain. I think i can the one with two taxonomies avoid to display the extra info term.

Comment: was the syntax error just on here, or did that make a difference on your site?

Comment: sry, the syntax error was only here a fault ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the 1st Solution, but the terms aren`t translated with -> i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, $language).

**EDIT**

The translation works with -> i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms($term). The language($language->language) in the $wrapper is not necessarry for the name translation:

```
    function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      if(arg(0)=="node" && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
        global $language;
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
        $variables['term'] = '';
        if(isset($wrapper->field_term_ref1)) {
          $term = $wrapper->language($language->language)->field_term_ref1->value();
          $translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms($term);
          $variables['term'] = $translated_term->name;
        }
        if(isset($wrapper->field_term_ref2)) {
          $term = $wrapper->field_term_ref2->value();
          $translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms($term);
          $variables['term'] = $translated_term->name;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I've edited my answer again to include term translation. Haven't tested it so I hope it works.

Comment: This doesn`t work, but no errors are shown. I try it with some other changes, but it is still in source language. The vocabulary settings are on localize and on other pages are all translations shown. Don`t know whats going wrong.

Comment: I see you've edited your answer after this comment, does that mean you got it working?

Comment: Yes. It works. Sry, i specify it better in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an [entity metadata wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) for this:

```
// Load the current active language.
global $language;
// Put the node object in a wrapper.
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
// Get the term object.
$term = $wrapper->language($language)->field_term_ref_1->value();
// Translate the term.
$translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, $language);
// Pass the term name to page.tpl.
$variables['term1'] = $translated_term->name;

// The same for term 2.

// Now you can print them in your page.tpl.
print $term1;
```

Not sure if the language part works, though.

Comment: Cool, 1st time i get the name! But it is not the translated. You changed the script. The $content works only for node.tpl i need it in the page.tpl

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope this will be more helpful to you.

Comment: i get -> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (Zeile 737 ... it works if i use the code directly in page.tpl but without translation.

Comment: Have you extracted the node object from $variables['node']?

Comment: Oh, you have right. but the code doesn`t work. i edit my question with last changes

Comment: After your edit you have a hook_preprocess_node with page.tpl.php, that won't work. As you said before, you need the hook_preprocess_page for that and get the node object from there.